# How do you select more than one element by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.3

I have two identical click events for two different elements that do not share a class,  as such:

```
$("#element_1").click(function(){
  alert("hello world");
});

$("#element_2").click(function(){
  alert("hello world");
});
```

I am looking for a way to assign that same click function to both of them without externalizing the function or repeating it (as seen above).
If the elements shared the same class, I would have done something like this:

```
$(".element_class").click(function(){
  alert("hello world");
});
```

but they do not. How do I achieve something like that in jQuery 1.3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#element_1, #element_2').bind('click', function() {...});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: thank you all for the information!
All voted up. First got marked as answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$('#element1, #element2').click();
```

Or

```
$('#element1').add('#element2').click();
```

Both methods are good